# how do i add an event to this code specifically for (.preventDefault()) and stoppropagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

```
function divFunction() {
         $('#edit-modal').modal();
}
```

How can I add an event in this code? I have tried this but it displays an error in firefox:

> typeerror: event undefined

```
function divFunction(event) {
   event.stopPropagation(); 

   var postBody = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].textContent;
   $('#post-body').val(postBody);   
   $('#edit-modal').modal();
}
```

This is how I call the function:

```html
@if(Auth::user()== $post->user) 
    <a href="#" name="edit" class="edit" onClick="divFunction()">Edit | </a> 
    <a href="{{ route('post.delete', ['post_id' => $post->id]) }} ">Delete | </a> 
@endif
```

Comment: How are you using the function?

Comment: How do you call `divFunction()` function?

Comment: @if(Auth::user()== $post->user)
                        <a href="#" name="edit" class="edit"  onClick=" divFunction()">Edit | </a>
                        <a href="{{ route('post.delete', ['post_id' => $post->id]) }} ">Delete | </a>
                     @endif

Comment: Please don't post code in a comment.  You can edit the question and include the information there.  Just click the `edit` link below the question (directly above these answers) to update the question with new information.

Comment: okay.. am kinda new to these, this is my first participation

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the event object into the function

```
<a href="#" name="edit" class="edit" onClick="divFunction(event)">Edit | </a>
```